# How to make ktlint-gradle work with Ktlint - IntelliJ IDEs Plugin. Including baseline support

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, ktlint

In my android project I want to use Ktlint - [IntelliJ IDEs Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15057-ktlint). This plugin requires a baseline file to be generated from the **root directory** of the project, but [ktlint-gradle](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle) generates it inside the `app` module. (Using `ktlintGenerateBaseline` task)

It is not about file location, I can configure the IDE plugin to look at the file in the app module,
but individual baseline entries have their relative paths start from the `app` module instead of the root directory.

For example: This is a file compatible with IDE plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<baseline version="1.0">
    <file name="app/src/androidTest/java/com/circula/MyTestRunner.kt">
        <error line="8" column="19" source="standard:colon-spacing" />
    </file>
</baseline>
```

But `ktlintGenerateBaseline` generates this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<baseline version="1.0">
    <file name="src/androidTest/java/com/circula/MyTestRunner.kt">
        <error line="8" column="19" source="standard:colon-spacing" />
    </file>
</baseline>
```

Note `app/src/androidTest` vs `src/androidTest`

Is there a way to make these two work together?

Thanks.